# is boost::multi_index still actively maintained?

Tags: c++, boost

It seems that Boost::Multi_index has not been updated for some time. Is this project still on?

Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it not do something you need? What are your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

The project is maintained:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/release_notes.html

Its author provides all needed support on boost-users mailing list.